# How to determine the direction of arrow on Feynman diagram for $W$ boson line?

Tags: conventions, feynman-diagrams, bosons

I am somewhat confused. Looking through these [slides (especially the 11th)](http://www.slideshare.net/asober/feynman-diagrams), which show Feynman diagrams involving $W$-bosons, I can't figure out which way to draw the arrow near the $W$ boson? How do people determine if it is to the "right" or to the "left".

Comment: Arrows usually show the flow of negative charge.

Comment: Could you please explain. Why is it to the  left (slide 13) and to the right (slide 15)?

Answer (score 3):

In general in  Feynman diagrams an incoming particle can be read as an outgoing antiparticle and W+ is the antiparticle of W- and vice verso. Quantum number conservation holds at the vertices. (charge , lepton number..)

The reaction studied in 11 is a change of a proton to a neutron through the weak interaction. The charge of the proton has to go to the right . The diagram has a W- going to the left, i.e. a W+ which is what is necessary for charge conservation on the second vertex.

For 13,  the reaction is a neutron turning into a proton by colliding with a neutrino. It has an arrow to the left  and when read towards the lepton vertex it is a W- , mathematicaly, which is what is needed for charge conservation.

For 15, the reaction is antineutrino proton , turning into e+ neutron. The arrow correctly conserves charge at the vertices.

Seems to me whoever wrote the site has been playing  games to make students think?